# Remove Filter with Mapbox GL JS

Tags: mapbox-gl-js

Using Mapbox GL JS 0.39.1, I set a filter on my layer:

```
map.setFilter('myLayer', ['!=', 'myKey', 'myValue'])
```

I cannot find a way to remove the filter. I would have thought there would be a map.removeFilter... function but have found nothing in the docs or in web searches. I could apply a fake filter (>'') so that it always matches but that seems inefficient. Surely there is a way to remove a filter.

EDIT: I have found that using the following code will achieve what I am trying to accomplish.  Not sure if this is the recommended approach.

```
map.setFilter('myLayer');
```

Answer (score 12):

The [docs](https://www.mapbox.com/mapbox-gl-js/api/#map#setfilter) were just updated, personally I would recommend using

```
map.setFilter('myLayer', null)
```

as it's more explicit and in my opinion makes the code more readable. Though your approach of just `map.setFilter('myLayer');` is also acceptable.